# mod_rewrite: Two websites, relative links to images. Rewrite image URL request to a single physical folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

There is a website A and a website B in `/en/` folder. So:
Website A: `http://domain/`
Website B: `http://domain/en/`
Both of the websites have `/images/` folder.

I want any requests to the images of the website B, to be redirected to the images of the website A. In other words:
`http://domain/en/images/*` → `http://domain/images/*`

This is what I tried to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1
```

And I have tried adding conditions like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. It didn't work.

What should be the contents of the .htacces file and in what physical folder I should put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an external redirect (actually send the browser to the new URL):

```
Redirect permanent /en/images/ /images/
```

Otherwise,

```
Alias /en/images /var/www/document_root/images/
```

This should go in the `<VirtualHost>` block for the website.

If **and only if** you do not have access to the virtual host configuration, and if you want an internal redirect, you can put this in `/var/www/document_root/en/images/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* /var/www/document_root/images/$0
```

Comment: I have access to <VirtualHost>, but I would prefer to use .htaccess, because, in case I have to move it to another domain, I would not depend on the server config. .htaccess will move together with it.
Is it a fair assumption?
Why <VirtualHost> is preferrable?

Comment: It saves processing power and file accesses, plus it can reduce your security risk in some cases. See the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when). And if you change servers/domains, you're going to have to transfer other changes in the main server configuration anyway, so you have little to lose by putting redirects there as well.

Comment: Putting `RewriteRule .* /var/www/document_root/images/$1` in .htaccess file in `/var/www/document_root/en/images/.htaccess` didn't do the job either. Now I'm getting blank page instead of 404 error, when I try to access `http://domain/en/images/1.jpg`

Comment: Ah, I made a typo. (This is another benefit of putting things in the main server configuration: the directives are frequently simpler)

Comment: Hm... it didn't work either... - blank page.
However, it works, if I put it this way: `RewriteRule (.*) /images/$1 [R,L]` it is redirecting browser properly. I tried the directives - no effect - I will discuss it with my hoster.

Answer (score 1):

If you put that in your document root, it should work, but if you want to redirect *the browser*, you need a `[R]` at the end of your RewriteRule, and to be safe, an `[L]`, too.

```
RewriteRule ^en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1  [R,L]
```

To redirect with a 301 (permanent), change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: It didn't work for `RewriteRule ^en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [R,L]` for reasons I don't know - still giving 404 error (e.g. for /en/images/1.jpg). Actually, it's Joomla website, and there are some rules in .htaccess for SEF urls. I have inserted the rule above the SEF rules.